# Include Non Code Files in Pod

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, cocoapods, assets

We are creating a private pod and would like to add following files with it.

- images
- sound files
- storyboards
- views/cells

Just wondering where we should mention those files in `.podspec` file?

Comment: Resource bundle is the place to add these [check here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation for [podspec resources](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resources), example:

```
spec.resources = ['Images/*.png', 'Sounds/*']
```

Also see [resource bundles](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles), example:

```
spec.resource_bundles = {
    'MapBox' => ['MapView/Map/Resources/*.png'],
    'OtherResources' => ['MapView/Map/OtherResources/*.png']
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Here you have an example of pod specfile that use Swift and PNG file, it could work for any type of file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'YourProject'
s.version          = '0.9.1'
s.summary          = 'iOS 10 Music Appshadow blur imitation'

s.description      = <<-DESC
Your description
DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/.....'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { '<YOUR NAME HERE>' => '<YOUR EMAIL HERE>' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/....', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
s.source_files = '...*.{swift,png}'

end
```

Here fore example all swift file and png file are integrated.
In order to use those file you need to use **the bundle of your pod project**.

For example in order to get an image you could do:

```
class func getImage(Named name : String,andExtension ext :String) -> UIImage?{
        
        if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: <YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER>),
            let imageUrl = bundle.url(forResource: name, withExtension: ext){
            
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl.path)
        }
        return nil
    }
```